# The Metaphsyics of Varna

Tags: scripture, caste-system, varna, gunas, varnashrama

Clarification of Metaphsyics

A clarification: By metaphysical I mean more the system in which it's decided and the various aspects of it ie what differs a Brahmin-Brahmin from a Brahmin-Chandala and a Chandala-Chandala over a Chandala-Brahminas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a single scripture that reconciles both. You have to look at it from various scriptures.

Also the history has to be looked upon to get a better understanding. By history I mean both type of histories: the first one is what historians have consensus on and the another is what termed as ‘mythology’. I do not prefer calling that a mythology.

A good question to start with would be: “Why there is not a dedicated scripture for varna system from the classical period?” From classical period I mean the period of Manu and early Aryans. The answers would be varying but are out of concerns of the question.

Further, you can investigate into how the system developed to get a metaphysical understanding.

Comment: What about acharyas do any of them have such scriptures even little insight shall do.

Comment: @Haridasa you can get things from here and there but I am not aware about any scripture that specifically deals with this.

Comment: Moreover, you can ask a question regarding this directly and I would answer that by next sunday or week (as it will require me to revisit scriptures). Please describe in the question what do you mean by “metaphysical”. Be specific in the question about what you really want

Comment: This answer currently correspond to the [original question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/58697/1). Will be updated to match current.

Comment: I will look into it I am gonna learn the 3 main dharmashastra.

Comment: Do you suggest any new works from 1700s or earlier?

Comment: You can read smritis to be precise. But you need to give a lot of thought to find what you are searching.@Haridasa